# require a local module in requirejs optimizer's callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, requirejs, gulp-watch

```
function test(){
    //optimize operation
    requirejs.optimize(profile, function(){
        //success callback
        //require local module hehe
        requirejs.config({
            baseUrl: 'scripts'
        });
        var nice = requirejs('hehe');
        console.log(nice);  
    }
    , function(err) {
        //failure operation
        console.log(err);
})};
```

I run requirejs in nodejs environment.(r.js)

It seemed that I could not get the module 'hehe' in the callback. The right output of console should be '2', while the current output is 'undefine'

But if I put the requirejs(...) var nice;console.log(nice) out of the callback. The output is correct.
The problem seemed to be related with the context in the requireJS.

```
function test（）{
requirejs.optimize(profile, function(){
    //success callback
    },
    function(err){
    console.log(err);
    }
);
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : 'scripts'
});
var nice = requirejs('hehe');
console.log(nice);}
```

And it confuses me that even if I put them out of callback , problem still exists when I use test() in gulp watch.

```
gulp.task("build", function(){
    test();
}):
gulp.task("watchsrc",function(){
    gulp.watch('*.js',['build']);
});
```

When I run gulp watch and modify src js file. At first time it works, console output is 2. But when I modify file the second time, the result becomes undefined again.

Comment: If you pull the `requirejs()` out of the callback, how do you set the value of `nice`? Are you running this in the browser or in Node?

Comment: Following steps are also moved out. In nodejs environment. r.js version2.3.4

Comment: Ok, then why are you trying to use RequireJS to load a module in the `optimize` callback? You could just use Node to load the module. (Yes, even if it is an AMD module you can load it with Node: you can use [`amd-loader`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader) for that.) Are you trying to load the bundle you've just created?

Comment: @Louis yes. It is an amd module（existing file） but not the bundle i have just created. It is an amd module containing config info. Loading in another way maybe a solution.